# Url with <int:pk> or <slug:slug> DJANGO

Tags: django, django-urls

Stumped with this one, I need to be able to call an article via a pk  or slug, for example user can do https://www.website.com/1 or https://www.website.com/article-slug both show the same article/page.

And if neither 1 or slug exist show default article or nothing found.

path('/', views.index, name='index’),
path('slug:slug/', views.index, name='index’)

Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = [
path('<int:pk>/', views.index),
path('<slug:slug>/',views.index)
]
```

`note`: remove the name attribute in the path because Django cannot decide where to go because the name is a unique identifier for each URL in your system or just make their names different.

another approach:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('<str:id_or_slug>/', views.index)
]
```

### in views

```
def get(self, request, id_or_slug):
try:
   # get element by pk

try:
   #get element by slug

except:
   #return that the element is not found
```

Comment: thanks buddy, worked a treat